# CRUD not able to displaly model instances in template to update

Tags: django, model, crud

I have an app project. I am able to save instances to the model in the database no problem. But I cannot pull in the instance by pk to the html form to edit and update. please see setup below can anyone provide any guidence or help, as to why this is not happening and how I can resolve?

views.py

```
def edit_properties(request, id):
     properties = Properties.objects.get(pk=id)
     context = {
         'properties': properties,
         'values': properties,
     }
     if request.method == 'GET':
         return render(request, 'sub/edit_properties.html', context)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. What is the exact error you are seeing when running this code?

Comment: Hi Jahongir,  it's not an error, it's just no matter the model form, get, approach, the saved instance, of the created data is not retruned to the html form. alowing me to edit it and then save it. I'm really stumped!

Answer (score 1):

you better use `ModelForm` to update data in your models

```
class PropertiesEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Properties
```

then you need to update your view to use this form

```
def edit_properties(request, id=None):
     properties = Properties.objects.get(pk=id) if id else None
     form = PropertiesEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=properties)
     if request.POST:
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("url_to_show_your_new_data")
     context = {
         'form': form,
     }
     return render(request, 'sub/edit_properties.html', context)
```

and in html file you use this form

```
<form method="POST" action="URL_TO_EDIT_PROPERTIES_VIEW">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for the help, unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. I'm still getting a blank Html form without the created saved instance of the data to be able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in my html the "{{values.address1}}" should be "{{values.Address1}}" as the attribute in the database is capital first letter.

Little less stressed now :)

```
    <div class="form-row my-3">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
    <label for="Addressline1">Address line 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" id="address1Field" 
    value="{{values.address1}}">
    </div>
```

Thank you all for your help,

Comment: that is why i said you need to use `modelform`, instead of  `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" id="address1Field" 
    value="{{values.1ddress1}}"> ` you will use `{form. 1ddress1}` and django will fill all values for you

Comment: Thanks Andrey, definately a smarter, cleaner and less problematic way to approach this. will implement.